# How to plot a graph with the same X but different Y value in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure, bar-chart

If my data looks like below:

```
X = [ 1 2  2  3  4  5 5]
Y = [10 9 -5 11 12 -3 7]
```

Can anyone please tell me how can I plot it as a bar char in Matlab? Because which I simply use bar(X, Y), it says that the XData can't not have duplicate values. The ideal situation is that in the same X position, there are two Y values. Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to split your data to 2 series: for positive and negative values of `y`. Then you can plot both on the same figure.

Note that since `bar` function uses relative width of bars, its depends on a minimal distance between `x` values in a data series. If those numbers are different in 2 data series, the bar width has to be corrected.

```
ipos = y>=0;
ineg = y<0;
dpos = min(diff(sort(x(ipos))));
dneg = min(diff(sort(x(ineg))));

w = 0.8;
bar(x(ipos),y(ipos),w);
hold on
bar(x(ineg), y(ineg), w*dpos/dneg, 'facecolor','r');
hold off
```

---

If you have more than 2 values per `x` you may want to use another approach to remove unique values through several iterations. In this case some values might become overlapped, so sort `y` first.

```
xx = x;
yy = y;
cla
hold on
w = 0.8;
while ~isempty(xx)
    [xu, idx]  = unique(xx);
    yu = yy(idx);
    xx(idx) = [];
    yy(idx) = [];
    d = min(diff(sort(xu)));
    bar(xu,yu,w/d);
end
hold  off
clear xx yy xu yu d
```

Answer (score 1):

From your question I think you want to plot a clustered bar chart. For this you must use a matrix in MATLAB. When you say `bar(A)` where `A` is a matrix, every column of `A` is taken as a data series, and will be plotted in clusters against natural numbers. So given your row data `X` and `Y`, you should do:

```
A=[X;Y]'; %note the single quote for transpose
bar(A)
```

Here's the output for your data (X blue, Y red):[image: MATLAB clustered bar graph]

Comment: Thanks Abhranil, but actually What I am looking for is some like with the same X values, but having two different Y values. (Also same Y values having two different X values).

Answer (score 0):

Use [`barh()`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/ref/barh.html) instead.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yet barh() gave me the same error message: `XData cannot contain duplicate values.` What I did was barh(X, Y)...

Comment: @Kevin: Then swap the arguments.  (I'm assuming that you want a horizontal bar graph; otherwise, I don't know how to interpret your desire to have multiple identical X values.)

Comment: it's the same because my Y has duplicate values in my actual datasheet.

Comment: @Kevin: In that case, I don't know what type of graph you're expecting.  Do you want multiple bars on top of each other?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
barh(Y,X), xlabel('X'), ylabel('Y')
```